# pass value from presentedViewController back to presentingViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios6, delegates, modalviewcontroller

Making APP for IOS 6 - I have a mainViewController that when tap on button a new modalViewController is presented. That modalViewController has a tableView. When user taps on a cell I want to take a value of that cell and assign it to variable on mainViewController.

The problem is that I always get NULL when I output it in viewDidAppear method.

This is delegate method in modalViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSMutableString *event_id = [[self.events valueForKey:@"event_id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"EVENT ID = %@", event_id); //This gives me actuall ID


    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.mainViewController setEventID:event_id];
    }];
}
```

If you see I use completion block to set it. In my mainViewController I have a property of eventID. In my modalViewController i also have

```
@class MainViewController

@interface ModalViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UITableView *eventsTable;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) MainViewController *mainViewController;

@end
```

For some reason I am getting eventID always NULL when I try to output it in viewDidAppear but it does output it when I first set it. What am I missing there??

Any help would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

In my MainViewController I already have other delegates set like this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Using protocol delegates approach, how would I add my custom delegate declaration there like ModalViewControllerDelegate.

Comment: Why are you setting the event ID in the completion block of `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`, rather than setting it before you dismiss the view?  Also, are you sure that `mainViewController` actually holds a valid reference to the main view controller?  And is the completion block getting called before or after `-viewDidAppear`?

Comment: I've put it in completion block cause I've tried setting it before i dismiss modal view controller and that didn't work either. It just doesn't set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a protocol/delegate to your ModalViewController and use that to communicate back to the MainViewController by subscribing to that delegate. Something like the following. (Not tested but gives you the idea). Be sure to set your delegate when you present your modal view like so.

[Study this link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/) if you are still having issues

```
ModalViewController *modal = (ModalViewController *)[[ModalViewController alloc]init];
modal.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController: modal animated:YES];
```

ModalViewController.h

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)setEventID:(id)event_ID;
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

ModalViewController.m

```
[_delegate setEventID:event_ID];
```

MainViewController.h

```
#import "ModalViewController.h"

MainViewController @interface ModalViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ModalViewControllerDelegate>
```

MainViewController.m

```
-(void)setEventID:(id)event_id
{
    [self setEventID:event_id];
}
```

Comment: I'll try this now and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is the right approach, however since I'm using protocols for the first time on my own I couldn't get it done. I'm still getting null out. I believe it's because I didn't set the delegates right. I already have other delegates on the same file. I edited my question, maybe you could give me some hints there. Would appreciate.

Comment: Check my edit. Also, don't forget to add the delegate like in my example. MainViewController @interface ModalViewController : UITableViewController <ModalViewControllerDelegate,OTHERDELEGATES...>

Comment: If I type MainViewController @interface ModalViewController : and so on, it throws me 2 errors. One saying "Cannot combine with previous type-name declaration specifier"  and the other one says "Duplicate interface definition  for class ModalViewController." So that doesn't really work for me.

Comment: What you just typed and what I typed are 2 different things. Update your question with your exact code please.

Comment: I figured it out with you help and guidelines. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSMutableString *event_id = [[self.events valueForKey:@"event_id"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"EVENT ID = %@", event_id); //This gives me actuall ID

    [self.mainViewController setEventID:event_id];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    }];
}
```

Comment: I tried that before I put the code in completion block but it doesn't set it. Either way it doesn't work.